# Water dripping from nose after swimming

Tags: swimming

After swimming in the sea, some amount of water drips from my nose time to time, for several hours. Normally water drips when I bend forward. Is this a medical problem?

Comment: I don't understand, is it coming from inside the nose? You would probably cough it out, if you inhale water... Can you please elaborate your question

Comment: Probably has to do with your timing of breathing, more info needed (swimstyle, pool vs open water). Maybe your question is about how to avoid it instead of worrying?

Comment: Probably not an issue and likely due to the salt content. Happens to me plenty of times. It's like shooting saline solution up your nose.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure it's definitely "water" and not just watery mucous? Pool swimming used to do that to me - now I wear a nose clip, and no longer have the problem (plus as a bonus I look super-attractive).

Comment: Edric - Why don't you wear nose plug instead of nose pin and still remain looking attractive..:)

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me as well when I swim in the ocean, but not when in a pool.  I attribute it to the roughness of the ocean which means that are always times when water goes into my nose and ends up in my sinuses.  Hours later a spurt of it will rush out, and then later another spurt, and so on.  It's annoying, but don't worry about, it doesn't mean you have anything wrong with you.  It's just that water can enter the sinus cavities, which are convoluted and can trap water.

(There is of course always some risk of infection, so if you later have pain behind your eyes, cheeks, or forehead, or a thick discolored discharge, or headaches, then you should see a physician.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is normal. Not just after swimming open water, although the waves and unpredictability of conditions make it harder to keep water out of your nose than in a pool. It is also completely normal to have water in your ears, for example.